# BarreCode EAN encoding

Tags: javascript

I try to generate the encoding of the EAN13 barcode in order to obtain for the code 6181100327649 the following line 6BSLLAA*dchgej+
This to be able to use the EAN font and generate in my creative visuals.
Here is my code but it does not work :

```js
function EAN(chaine) {
var i           = 0;
var first       = 0;
var checksum    = 0;
var CodeBarre   = "";
var tableA      = 0;

        if(chaine.match("/^\d{12}$/")){
                for (i = 1; i < 12; i += 2)
                {
                    chaine.substr(i, 1);
                    checksum += parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1));
                }
                checksum *= 3;
                for (i = 0; i < 12; i += 2)
                {
                    checksum += parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1));
                }

                chaine += (10 - checksum % 10) % 10;
                CodeBarre = chaine.substr(0, 1) + (chaine.fromCharCode(65 + parseInt(chaine.substr(1, 1)) ));
                first = parseInt(chaine.substr(0, 1));
                for (i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
                {
                    tableA = false;
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 2: if (first >= 0 && first <= 3) tableA = true; break;
                        case 3: if (first == 0 || first == 4 || first == 7 || first == 8) tableA = true; break;
                        case 4: if (first == 0 || first == 1 || first == 4 || first == 5 || first == 9) tableA = true; break;
                        case 5: if (first == 0 || first == 2 || first == 5 || first == 6 || first == 7) tableA = true; break;
                        case 6: if (first == 0 || first == 3 || first == 6 || first == 8 || first == 9) tableA = true; break;
                    }

                    if (tableA)
                        CodeBarre += (chaine.fromCharCode(65 + parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1)) ));
                    else
                        CodeBarre += (chaine.fromCharCode(75 + parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1)) ));
                }
                CodeBarre += "*";

                for (i = 7; i <= 12; i++)
                {
                    CodeBarre += (chaine.fromCharCode(97 + parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1)) ));
                }
                CodeBarre += "+";
            }
            return CodeBarre;
        }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = EAN("618110032764");
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _"but it does not work"_. Do you get any errors? Please show how you use the function. Provide some example inputs and the expected outputs, as well as what you currently get.

Comment: I have an error message here : document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = EAN("618110032764"); Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the issue. Include the HTML. We cannot debug code we cannot see

Comment: You need to replace this line ` if (chaine.match(/^\d{12}$/)) {` remove the '' as it's a regex, but even then it won't work, I am doing a little working example for u here

Comment: Thank you Ziyed, now I have error here CodeBarre = chaine.substr(0, 1) + (chaine.fromCharCode(65 + parseInt(chaine.substr(1, 1)) ));, please ?

Comment: Working on an example, but issue is that fromCharCode is static , you need to use it with String.fromCharCode, I am still looking at your logic which I think is incorrect

Comment: Updated with the answer, don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was mutliple issues here, but here is a working example for you

```
function getCharCode(chaine, index, position) {
  return String.fromCharCode(position + parseInt(chaine.substr(index, 1)));
}

function EAN(chaine) {
  var i = 0;
  var first = 0;
  var checksum = 0;
  var CodeBarre = "";
  var tableA = 0;

  if (chaine.match(/^\d{12}$/)) {
    for (i = 1; i < 12; i += 2) {
      chaine.substr(i, 1);
      checksum += parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1));
    }
    checksum *= 3;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i += 2) {
      checksum += parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1));
    }

    chaine += (10 - checksum % 10) % 10;
    CodeBarre = chaine.substr(0, 1) + getCharCode(chaine, 1, 65);
    first = parseInt(chaine.substr(0, 1));
    for (i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
      tableA = false;
      switch (i) {
        case 2:
          if (first >= 0 && first <= 3) tableA = true;
          break;
        case 3:
          if (first == 0 || first == 4 || first == 7 || first == 8) tableA = true;
          break;
        case 4:
          if (first == 0 || first == 1 || first == 4 || first == 5 || first == 9) tableA = true;
          break;
        case 5:
          if (first == 0 || first == 2 || first == 5 || first == 6 || first == 7) tableA = true;
          break;
        case 6:
          if (first == 0 || first == 3 || first == 6 || first == 8 || first == 9) tableA = true;
          break;
      }

      if (tableA)
        CodeBarre += getCharCode(chaine, i, 65); 
      else
        CodeBarre += getCharCode(chaine, i, 75); 
    }
    CodeBarre += "*";

    for (i = 7; i <= 12; i++) {
      CodeBarre += getCharCode(chaine, i, 97); 
    }
    CodeBarre += "+";
  }
  return CodeBarre;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = EAN("618110032764");
```

Among those issues :

- Regex shouldn't be a string so no `""` surrounding the expression
- fromCharCode is a static method, should be used with String.fromCharCode
- You should access characters from the string with the index on the loop

Here is the working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t6r15qbd/1/

Comment: Another error here: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = EAN("618110032764"); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Comment: You need to have a div in your document with the id demo, which doesn't seem to be ur case, you can simply replace that line with a console log if you wanna verify the function
I've added a jsfiddle for you to try

Comment: Thank you very much, the DIV was below the code, I just moved it to the beginning of the page.
Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to come back to this topic, but can you give me another hand?
I can't get the encoding in txt_encoding

please, can you complete your help and help me?

```js
function getCharCode(chaine, index, position) {return String.fromCharCode(position + parseInt(chaine.substr(index, 1)));}

function EAN(chaine) {
        var code_ean13_sivop    = document.getElementById("txt_ean13_sivop");
        var txt_ean             = document.getElementById("txt_ean");
        var txt_encodage        = document.getElementById("txt_encodage");
        txt_ean.value           = code_ean13_sivop.options[code_ean13_sivop.selectedIndex].text.substr(0, 12);
    
    var i = 0;
    var first = 0;
    var checksum = 0;
    var CodeBarre = "";
    var tableA = 0;
        
    if (chaine.match(/^\d{12}$/)) {
        for (i = 1; i < 12; i += 2) {chaine.substr(i, 1); checksum += parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1));}
        checksum *= 3;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i += 2) {checksum += parseInt(chaine.substr(i, 1));}
        chaine += (10 - checksum % 10) % 10;
        CodeBarre = chaine.substr(0, 1) + getCharCode(chaine, 1, 65);
        first = parseInt(chaine.substr(0, 1));
        for (i = 2; i <= 6; i++) {
            tableA = false;
            switch (i) {
                case 2: if (first >= 0 && first <= 3) tableA = true; break;
                case 3: if (first == 0 || first == 4 || first == 7 || first == 8) tableA = true; break;
                case 4: if (first == 0 || first == 1 || first == 4 || first == 5 || first == 9) tableA = true; break;
                case 5: if (first == 0 || first == 2 || first == 5 || first == 6 || first == 7) tableA = true; break;
                case 6: if (first == 0 || first == 3 || first == 6 || first == 8 || first == 9) tableA = true; break;
            }
            if (tableA) CodeBarre += getCharCode(chaine, i, 65); else CodeBarre += getCharCode(chaine, i, 75); 
        }
        CodeBarre += "*";
        for (i = 7; i <= 12; i++) {CodeBarre += getCharCode(chaine, i, 97); }
        CodeBarre += "+";
    }
    return CodeBarre;

txt_encodage.value = EAN(txt_ean.value);
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control form-control-sm text-monospace" id="txt_ean13_sivop" name="txt_ean13_sivop" onChange="EAN();">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option  value="6181100327847">6181100327847</option>
    <option  value="6181100327854">6181100327854</option>
    <option  value="6181100328080">6181100328080</option>
    <option  value="6181100328097">6181100328097</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-monospace" id="txt_ean" name="txt_ean">
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-monospace" id="txt_encodage" name="txt_encodage">
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yd7ru2wc/1/ , your inputs are 13 characters long so I've updated the regex + updated the logic there, take a close look at what changed and why